# How do i set varible value as a file name

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I tried this but it's not working, I am trying to do is set the value of text to file name

```
var x = content.document.forms[0].elements[1].name;
var text = (x) + ".txt"   ;


var file = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"]
           .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);
file.initWithPath("D:\\+ (text) +");
```

Comment: java != javascript

Comment: `file.initWithPath("D:\\"+ text)`?

Comment: @guest271314 thanks...working